# Select First and Last Dates from Range selection of Dates

Tags: java, android, calendar

I've been Trying to create an Android application which able to select multiple days from the calendar, and display first and last Dates of the selection in different TextViews and Update that event in a Firestore Database.

this is the Calendar Activity class
CalendarActivity.Java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class CalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     String eventStartDate ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final CalendarPickerView calendar_view = (CalendarPickerView) 
        findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
            //getting currentS
        Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        Date today = new Date();



            //add one year to calendar from todays date
        calendar_view.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
                .inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.RANGE);

        //action while clicking on a date
        calendar_view.setOnDateSelectedListener(new 
        CalendarPickerView.OnDateSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(Date date) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected Date is : " +date.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                eventStartDate=date.toString();


                }



            @Override
            public void onDateUnselected(Date date) {

               //...
            }
        });

        //fetch dates

        final List<Date> dates = calendar_view.getSelectedDates();

        //final int eventEndDateIndex = dates.lastIndexOf(dates);
        //eventStartDate = dates.get(0);
        //eventEndDate= dates.get(eventEndDateIndex);



        //Displaying all selected dates while clicking on a button
        Button btn_show_dates = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_dates);
        btn_show_dates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int j=0;

                for (int i = 0; i< calendar_view.getSelectedDates().size();i++){

                    //here you can fetch all dates
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),calendar_view.getSelectedDates().get(i).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });


    }
}
```

And this is the Layout File
activity_calendar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CalendarActivity">

    <com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="467dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_show_dates"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_show_dates"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Display Dates"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventStartDate"
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:text="Event Start Date"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="472dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventEndDate"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:text="Event End Date"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="252dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="472dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is your question? How is not answered by the many thousands of Questions and Answers already posted on this topics?

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of selected days as Date objects:

```
calendar_view.getSelectedDates();
```

Using a compare function such as:

```
           Collections.sort(your_dates, new Comparator<Date>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Date d1, Date d2) {
                    if(d1.getTime() > d2.getTime())
                        return 1;
                    else if(d1.getTime() < d2.getTime())
                        return -1;
                    return 0;
                }
            });
```

Then you can just access the first and last element of the list.

Comment: The old-fashioned `Date` class implements `Comparable`, so wouldn’t it work without the comparator? I would think so.

Comment: I was not aware of that. I'm not too familiar with the Date class, so there might be much better ways to do it. Good to know though.